# Oracle RegExp_Like for Two Repeating Digits

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to write a regexp_like function which would identify if a string consists of two repeating characters. It would only identify a string that has alternating numbers and only consisting of two unique numbers, but the unique number cannot repeat, it must alternate.

**Requirement :**

Regular expression should match the pattern for `787878787`, but it should **NOT** match the pattern `787878788`
It should NOT consider the pattern like `000000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT '787878787' AS str FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT '787878788' AS str FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT '7878787878' AS str FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT '78' AS str FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM t1
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^(.)(.)(\1\2)*\1?$')
   AND SUBSTR(str, 1, 1) != SUBSTR(str, 2, 1)
```

This will cover the case (mentioned in the requirements) where the string ends with the same character with which it begins. If you want only digits, replace the `.` in the regex with `\d`.

**Update:**

Here is how the regex breaks down:

```
^ = start of string
(.) = first character - can be anything - in parentheses to capture it and use it in a backreference
(.) = second character - can be anything
\1 = backreference to first captured group
\2 = backreference to second captured group
(\1\2)* = These should appear together zero or more times
\1? = The first captured group should appear zero or one times
$ = end of the string
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This solution does identify the case of "787878787" but it also returns values that are all the same digit such as "000000000". Is there anyway to specify that more than one unique digit must be present?

Comment: David, thank you! Would it be possible for you to provide a breakdown of each part of the REGEXP_LIKE function to show what each part does, similar to what gwillie provided in one of the previous responses..? I understand the substring part, no need to clarify on that.

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like this -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '787878787' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '787878788' FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT *
  6  FROM DATA
  7  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(str, '(\d+?)\1')
  8  AND SUBSTR(str, 1,1) = SUBSTR(str, -1, 1)
  9  /

STR
---------
787878787

SQL>
```

Since you are dealing only with digits, I used `\d`.

`\d+?` will match the digits, and, `\1` are the captured digits. The `substr` in the `AND` condition is checking whether the first and last digit of the string are same.

**Edit : Additional requirement by OP**

To avoid the numbers like `00000000`, you need to add a `NOT` condition to the predicate.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT '787878787' str FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '787878788' FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT '787878788' FROM dual
  7    )
  8  SELECT *
  9  FROM DATA
 10  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(str, '(\d+?)\1')
 11  AND SUBSTR(str, 1,1)  = SUBSTR(str, -1, 1)
 12  AND SUBSTR(str, 2,1) <> SUBSTR(str, -1, 1)
 13  /

STR
---------
787878787

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This solution does identify the case of "787878787" but it also returns values that are all the same digit such as "000000000". Is there anyway to specify that more than one unique digit must be present?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is add a `NOT` condition. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
^(..)\1*$
```

Breakdown:

```
^    - assert beginning of line
(..) - capture the first 2 characters
\1*  - repeat the captured group pattern zero or more times
$    - assert end of line
```

Untested in oracle...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately after testing it, it did not identify the value as desired